# Not sure why finalize operator not running

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

In my component, I have a handler for clicking the save button that looks like this:

```js
saveClicked() {
    ...
    this._requests
        .updateEquipmentRequest(updatedRequest)
        .pipe(finalize(() => (this.saving = false)))
        .subscribe(() =>
            this._toasts.success('Request updated', 'Success')
        );
}
```

The `updateEquipmentRequest` call looks like this:

```js
updateEquipmentRequest(request: EquipmentRequest): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('request', JSON.stringify(request));
    const result = this._http
        .put(
            `${environment.api.url}/EquipmentRequests/${request.id}`,
            formData
        )
        .pipe(
            debug('updated equipment request'),
            tap(() => {
                const index = this._requests.findIndex(
                    (r) => r.id === request.id
                );
                this._requests[index] = request;
                this._requests$.next(this._requests);
            }),
            shareReplay(1)
        );

    return result;
}
```

I also have an HttpInterceptor that has this in it:

```js
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
        .handle(req)
        .pipe(catchError((error) => this.handleHttpErrorResponse(error)));
}

private handleHttpErrorResponse(response: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (typeof response.error === 'string') {
        const message = response.error;
        this._toastNotificationService.show(
            response.statusText,
            message,
            ToastType.error
        );
    } else if (
        response.error instanceof ProgressEvent &&
        response.status === 0 &&
        response.statusText === 'Unknown Error'
    ) {
        // Seems to be an indication that a connection wasn't even made to the server.
        const message =
            'Unable to connect to the server.  Please contact support';
        this._toastNotificationService.show(
            'HttpErrorResponse',
            message,
            ToastType.error
        );
    }
    return throwError(response);
}
```

In the component, I'm using the `saving` property to control the disabled state of the button.  But when I get an error response from the server, the `finalize` operator is never fired.  Thus, my buttons stay disabled until a page refresh.  I figure I could also set `this.saving = false` in another `catchError` operator, but I'd rather have that in one spot.  And in other parts of my application, this works for me.  I can't see any difference in approach between this api call and other api calls that do have their `finalize` operator fire.

So I started looking into if the observable is completing at all.  As far as I understand it, if there is an error, then the `finalize` operator should be called, but it doesn't seem to.  I've looked at other questions on StackOverflow related to this, and it seemed to work for other people as long as you returned an Observable in your `catchError` operator, which I'm doing with `throwError(error)`.

Why doesn't the `finalize` operator get invoked at this point?

### Update

I tried setting `this.saving = false` in the error callback as well, and even though that runs, `this.saving = false` doesn't seem to be doing anything as putting `{{saving}}` in the template next to the buttons shows that after the error occurs, the button is still disabled and `saving` is still true from the template's perspective:

```js
...
    this._requests
        .updateEquipmentRequest(updatedRequest)
        .pipe(finalize(() => (this.saving = false)))
        .subscribe(
            () => this._toasts.success('Request updated', 'Success'),
            (error) => {
                this.saving = false;
                console.log('Error');
            }
        );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this component is using the `OnPush` `ChangeDetectionStrategy` and if I turn saving into a `BehaviorSubject`, I can get the UI to update as expected, and the `finalize` operator was running all along.

I have to admit I don't quite understand why a non-observable component property change doesn't update the template in this case, but I guess nothing is firing a change detection cycle when I get an http error.